# Match lines not starting with first two specific characters

Tags: regex, grep, pcre

I'm trying to match lines that do not begin with "CD" or any 2-digit number. I've tried:

```
^[^Cc0-9][^Dd0-9].+?$
```

but it does not match lines that begin with "Cx" or "0y".

I'm using a program called [rxrepl](https://sites.google.com/site/regexreplace/) with the above regex as the search string and nothing as the replacement. I'm trying to avoid using grep. Also I can't use parentheses because in rxrepl they are used to capture groups.

Comment: `^(?:CD|\d{2}).+?$`

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using parentheses? They are used for capturing groups in rxrepl.

Comment: `(?:` will avoid capturing

Comment: @PranavCBalan: No, you can't. That will match CD at the beginning of the string or two digits anywhere. The `.+` and `.+?` are also weird and superfluous

Comment: `^(?:CD|\d{2}).+?$` does the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve. You see in my expression I'm actually trying to match lines not beginning with CD or 2 digit numbers so I can replace them with nothing so that only lines starting with CD and a two digit number remain.

Comment: `^CD.+$|^\d{2}.+$` or `^(?:CD|\d{2}).+$`

Comment: @zcalebz: So why did you write *"I'm trying to match lines in a file beginning with "CD" or any 2-digit number."*

Comment: @zcalebz: I think my solution below solves your problem. What more do you want?

Comment: @Borodin It works. Thanks to you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, you need

```
^(?:CD|\d\d)
```

The `(?: ... )` is a *non-capturing* group

Or if you *must* avoid parentheses of any sort then use

```
^CD|^\d\d
```

---

#### Update

To comply with your new spec *"I'm actually trying to match lines* **not** *beginning with CD or 2 digit numbers"*

```
^(?!CD|\d\d)
```

You need to get over your problem with the parentheses. A negative look-ahead is [fine in PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC19) and *does not capture*

Answer (score 2):

It is either `CD` or two numbers. So you have to use groups `(group1|group2)` like this:

```
^(CD|[0-9]{2})
# ^^ ^^^^^^^^
# |         |   
# either CD |
#           or two digits
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using parentheses? They are used for capturing groups in rxrepl.

Comment: You can use a [non-capturing group (?:)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/1983854).